# onclick isn't working with button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a javascript function work on pressing delete button but the function doesnt seem to run.

Here's the button

```
 <button class="tiny" id="bookmark_delete" onlclick="ajax_bookmark()">Delete</button>
```

Here's the JS

```
    function ajax_bookmark(){
      var abc = $('#b_delete').val();
      var cde = $('#currect_req_b_id').val();
      $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "delete_bookmark",
    data: {
      d:abc,
      d1:cde
    },
        error:function(){

    },
    dataType: 'json',
    //beforeSend:function(){},
    //complete:function(o,s){},
    success:function(data){
      location.href ="/bookmarks/bookmark"
    },
    type: 'get'
  });
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Delete extra l from onlclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your html. You are using onlclick instead of onclick:

```
 <button class="tiny" id="bookmark_delete" onclick="ajax_bookmark()">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a typo in the `onclick` attribute of your button tag:

`<button class="tiny" id="bookmark_delete" onlclick="ajax_bookmark()">Delete</button>`

Should be:

`<button class="tiny" id="bookmark_delete" onclick="ajax_bookmark()">Delete</button>`

Working snippet:

```js
function foo(){
  $('button').html('I was clicked!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="foo()">DoFoo</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your code. Also is a bad practice use an `onclick()` , so you should do it like that:

html:

```
<button class="tiny" id="bookmark_delete">Delete</button>
```

js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#bookmark_delete').on('click', function(){
        var abc = $('#b_delete').val();
        var cde = $('#currect_req_b_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "delete_bookmark",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
              d: 'abc',
              d1: 'cde'
            },
            success:function(data){
              location.href ="/bookmarks/bookmark"
            }, 
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
    });
});
```

Take a look the DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6e0749uk/

hope it´s helps.